# Installing MySql2 gem on OpenIndiana 151

Tags: rubygems, solaris, mysql2, opensolaris

I am attempting to install the mysql2 gem on OpenIndiana 151 without success :(

I have the MySQL 5.1 server/client/library packages installed:

```
$ pkg list | grep mysql
database/mysql-51                             5.1.37-0.151.1  installed  -----
database/mysql-51/library                     5.1.37-0.151.1  installed  -----
database/mysql-common                         0.5.11-0.151.1  installed  -----
```

But when I attempt to install the gem:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.2.17' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/mysql/5.1/bin/mysql_config
```

I get the following output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/aburns/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/mysql/5.1/bin/mysql_config
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/home/aburns/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-solaris2.11 -I/home/aburns/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/aburns/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H -I/home/aburns/.rvm/usr/include  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I/usr/mysql/5.1/include/mysql  -xprefetch=auto -xprefetch_level=3 -mt -fns=no -fsimple=1 -xbuiltin=%all -xlibmil -xlibmopt -xnorunpath   -DHAVE_RWLOCK_T -DUNIV_SOLARIS -fPIC -O3 -g -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -Wall -funroll-loops  -o mysql2_ext.o -c mysql2_ext.c
gcc: language norunpath not recognized
gcc: mysql2_ext.c: linker input file unused because linking not done
[[ snip dependent compile errors ]]
gcc: mysql2_ext.o: No such file or directory
gcc: result.o: No such file or directory
gcc: client.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [mysql2.so] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/aburns/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@quibbler/gems/mysql2-0.2.17 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/aburns/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@quibbler/gems/mysql2-0.2.17/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

As you can see GCC fails with the **gcc: language norunpath not recognized**.

I am not familiar enough with GCC our native gem building to know what to do next.

Based on my research I think `norunpath` is a Sun specific flag that GCC does not support; however I am not sure how, or even if, I can remove it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about it on my [blog](http://mattconnolly.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/installing-mysql2-gem-on-openindiana/) a while ago:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/gnu/bin:$PATH
$ gem install mysql2 -v '0.2.18' -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/mysql/5.1 --with-mysql-include=/usr/mysql/5.1/include/mysql
```

Comment: Holly crap I hope this works!  Thanks Matt, I really like the OI platform but this was a deal breaker for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's an awesome platform. Been a few struggles getting rails up and running. My patch for passenger has finally been included, and passenger 3.0.13 should be all systems go if your using a rails app and apache. Good luck!